# discrete event modelling for a bank in anylogic

Tags: modeling, anylogic

I am doing a discrete event modelling for a banking system using anylogic.

There sequence is as follow.

[system modelling example that I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMKVE.png)

1. Clients will arrive and 0.5 will go straight to the service desk while the other will use the ATM.
2. 0.3 that uses the ATM will go to the service desk to do other transaction. the remaining 0.2 will exit the bank.

Q. how do I get the the average for cashier utilization at the service desk and the average queuing time at the service desk?

Answer (score 0):

Resource utilization can be obtained with the RessourcePool.utilization() method, as documented here : [LINK](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resourcepool.html)

For average queue times, the most straightforward way that involves minimal non-graphical programming would be to split your service block into Seize, Delay, and Release blocks, and set Time Measure blocks around the Seize.